# How do I write a node.js file with PHP?

Tags: php, node.js

I need to write a node.js script, that is stored in a variable, so that I can change the code on the fly with variables, however when I escape all the "s, It throws out many syntax errors. Some especially tricky parts were in the code: `+ id + '" />\0');` and other locations were \ is used. How do I do this?

Comment: Post the code you've written. I don't understand your question without it.

Comment: I need to use fopen() to write a script to file, with edited variables, however the script has escape charecters and other things which fopen() does not write

Comment: @GeorgeWBush Why do you want to write a Node.js file in PHP when Node.js is clearly written in Javascript. You can do almost everything in Javascript that PHP can do.

Comment: I can't tell if you're trolling, but if you're not: Node.js is a script interpreter for .js files, using the Node.js API, in the same way PHP is a script interpreter for .php using Zend's PHP API - what you're asking makes absolutely no sense. It's the same as asking about "needing to write a C++ program that's stored in a variable in Java"

Comment: My goal is this: to change a node.js script from a web panel, using PHP to write the file from a variable. The script is stored in a variable and I use preg_replace to edit the bits that I want to change for the script.